# What does it means for a sample to be random?

Tags: statistics, random, sampling

For a sample to be random, I thought it means that every member has an equal chance of being selected.

However, it seems like it is insufficient to just say the above. May I know what is the proper definition for a random sample? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question; it isn't always clear what "random" means. Your first definition is an example of a _uniform distribution_, where everything is equally likely. You may be interested in [algorithmic information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_information_theory), a CS field that talks about this kind of thing.

Comment: "It seems like it is insufficient to just say the above." Have you encountered a particular example of a "random sample" for which it was insufficient? It might help if you would give more detail about what made you ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sampling $m$ items (without replacement) from a finite population of items, you want every set of $m$ distinct items in the population to have equal probability of being your sample.  If sampling with replacement, you want every ordered $m$-tuple to have equal probability of being your sample.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, "random" does not simply mean that each element is "equally probable" or "equally likely" to appear.  That is just one *particular* distribution:  the *uniform distribution*.  Instead, samples can be "random" even if there probabilities are unequal.  For example, a "weighted coin" which has a 60% of being HEADS, 40% chance of being TAILS is technically random.